# rich:tooltip not working for RichFaces 4

Tags: richfaces, tooltip

Version :

RichFaces 4.3.5

Apache MyFaces 2.1

Issue :

We are migrating from rich faces 3 to 4.
We are facing following issue for rich:tooltip component.
As shown in listing 1 , when tooltip is included inside rich:dataTable , it is showing fine.
But when included without rich:dataTable , it is not showing up.
When mode="ajax" is added in Listing 2 , it starts working , but we don't want to use ajax mode and want content to be prefetched.

Is there any way we can get Listing 2 working with client mode ?

Code :

Listing 1 :

```
 <rich:dataTable id="apps" value="#{bean.values}" var="val">
                <f:facet name="header">
                <rich:columnGroup columnClasses="rowClass">
                    <h:column>
                    <h:outputText value="Column1" />
                </h:column>                                                     
                </rich:columnGroup>
            </f:facet>
            <h:column>
                    <h:panelGroup rendered="#{bean.condition}">
                        <h:outputText id="statusId" style="cursor:hand; color:#0000F0; text-decoration:underline;" value="#{val.statusValue}" />
                    <rich:tooltip target="statusId" showEvent="click" direction="bottomLeft"  followMouse="false" layout="block" >
                        <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                            <h:panelGroup>
                                <h:outputLabel value="Detail Status " rendered="#{val.statusDescr}" />                              
                            </h:panelGroup>
                        </h:panelGrid>
                    </rich:tooltip>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </h:column>
 </rich:dataTable>
```

Listing 2 :

```
<h:panelGroup>
    <h:outputText id="statusIdMain" style="cursor:hand; color:#0000F0; text-decoration:underline;" value="#{bean.statusValue}" />
    <rich:panel>
        <h:outputText id="statusId" style="cursor:hand; color:#0000F0; text-decoration:underline;" value="#{val.statusValue}" />
        <rich:tooltip target="statusId" showEvent="click" direction="bottomLeft"  followMouse="false" layout="block" >
                <h:panelGrid columns="1">
                    <h:panelGroup>
                        <h:outputLabel value="Detail Status " rendered="#{bean.statusDescr}" />                             
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </h:panelGrid>
        </rich:tooltip>
    </rich:panel>
</h:panelGroup>
```

**EDIT 1 :**

It is also observed that sometimes tooltip content is shown after clicking the text targeted for tooltip a couple of times.

**EDIT 2  :**
I have observed one more thing .When direction="bottomLeft" is used for the tooltip , tolltip doesn't show but after replacing with "bottomRight" , it starts working. On console debug for the first case , I have observed warning for CSS as : 
"Error in parsing value for 'left'.  Declaration dropped. 
Error in parsing value for 'top'.  Declaration dropped."

Comment: I can see the tooltip just fine (although you have two components with the same id in your code). Have you checked the generated code for the tooltip (`div.rf-tt`) and the JS code (`new RichFaces.ui.Tooltip(…)`)?

Comment: Thanks for you repply Makhiel. I have observed one more thing.When direction="bottomLeft" is used for the tooltip , tolltip doesn't show but after replacing with "bottomRight" , it starts working. On console debug for the first case , I have observed warning for CSS as : "Error in parsing value for 'left'.  Declaration dropped. 
Error in parsing value for 'top'.  Declaration dropped."

Comment: Those are just CSS errors, that shouldn't be the cause.

Comment: Do it simple: remove `<h:panelGrid columns="1">` and `<h:panelGroup>`. You can rewrite it in following format: `<h:panelGroup id="passwordTooltip">  <h:outputText value="&#8225;" styleClass="comment" />  <rich:tooltip mode="client" layout="block">      <h:outputText value="#{msg.passwordInfo}" escape="false"/>  
</rich:tooltip>  </h:panelGroup>`